# Need help Understanding Concept of Pumping Lemma & Regular Languages

Tags: automata

So my professor suddenly decided to make our homework difficult. He did not provide any examples or ways to proof so now I've been stuck on this for a while. [image]

I'm not asking for the solution but rather the right direction in order to get the right answer.

Comment: Consider not only the words that make up the language to check for regularity but also the length of the words.

Comment: Ex. 1.3 is one of the seemingly hard questions that, after you understand the solution, becomes much simpler. For that, you need to visualize that the set must satisfy a few key properties that allow you to conclude. Suppose you found a word in the language -- can you then immediately find many other related words in the language?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some brief ideas on the pumping lemma that might help get you started.

Essentially the pumping lemma says:

- Any DFA must have a cycle in it at some point. It takes at most $P$ transitions to go from the start state to the end of the cycle. We call $P$ the pumping length.
- We can then break up any word $S$ into three parts:

  - The characters it takes to get from the start state to the beginning of the cycle
  - The characters it takes to go around the cycle (once or more)
  - The characters it takes to get from the end of the cycle to some ending state

That's more or less the same as saying:

- $S = xy^iz$, where:

  - $|xy| \leq P$
  - $|y| \geq 1$ ($y$ is essentially the characters it takes to loop the cycle once)
  - $i \geq 0$ ($i$ is essentially the number of times you go around the cycle)

So you can basically use this as a jumping off point:
If you can show that a DFA for a language can't have a cycle in it (that is, it does not satisfy the pumping lemma), then it can't be a regular language.